# iphone image saving

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I can save image to iPhone (iPhone Photo Albums \ Saved Photos) with

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, onCompleteTarget, onCompleteSelector, contextInfoToCompleteSelector);
```

But if there any way to check, if current image was already saved (to save it only once)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an unique filename for your image, you could use NSFileManager for checking, if the file already exists.

```
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileName]) {
  //File exists
}
else {
  // File doesn't exist
}
```